# sending multi-digit integers from python to arduino through pyserial

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I want to send a number(say 90) from python to arduino through pyserial. But I guess arduino works with ASCII only. So how do I read the integer 90 in arduino ? please help...

Comment: Arduino works with bytes, no ascii. You can send a byte with the value `90` or convert the string `'90'` into an integer in arduino.

Answer (score 1):

In Python it is easy to convert a number as a string: You can just do

```
str(90)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str

Then in the Arduino code, you can use

```
parseInt()
```

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/ParseInt

Or you can just send binary data over the serial line. If your number is always between 0 and 255, you can just send one byte. Otherwise you will have to send the number in several bytes.